# CSS border mpdf output

Tags: css, pdf, mpdf

Here is what is going on. What is happening I'm using mpdf as output and for some reason I can't get the CSS output to work.

Here is the CSS code:

```
td colspan="2" style="border-bottom:2px dashed #000;"
```

Is there a way that the CSS be used for the PDF output?

Comment: can you show the rest of the code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mpdf=new mPDF();
$html = "<H1>Hello World</H1>";
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('style.css');  
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);    // The parameter 1 tells that this is css/style only and no body/html/text
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```